# CountDownTimer incorrectly sets text to more view than asked for

Tags: android

On the `CountDownTimer` `onFinish` method, I want to set 2 string to 2 different views like this

```
public void onFinish() {
            setText(timer, getString(R.string.times_up));
            setText(speedTextView, speedValue);

            setColorTimer(timer, Color.RED);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
        }
```

However, when the timer finished, the `R.string.times_up` value is casted to both `timer` and `speedTextView` view. I changed the order of the 2 lines and in that case, the `speedValue` is casted on both view, although they should be 2 different method calls.

`setText` method is a modified one to run them on the main thread instead of the background thread like this

```
private void setText(final TextView text, String value) {
    speedValueToSetText = value;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(speedValueToSetText);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I resolve this? Shouldn't the setText methods be independent to each other?

Comment: where is Timer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable `speedValueToSetText` cause the error.Remove this line `speedValueToSetText = value;`.The `setText` should be

```
private void setText(final TextView text, String value) {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(value);
    }
});
```

}

or

```
private void setText(final TextView text, String value) {
    speedValueToSetText = value;
    final String resultValue = value;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(resultValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: then it will require the String to be final, I want it to update so I should avoid it.

Comment: If you need the```speedValueToSetText```, you can  edit the code as below,    private void setText(final TextView text, String value) {
        speedValueToSetText = value;
        final String resultValue = value;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText(resultValue);
            }
        });
    }
I have updated my answer.

Comment: it worked, thanks, but can I ask why did it behave like that in the first place?

Comment: ```speedValueToSetText = value;``` and ```text.setText(speedValueToSetText);``` are in different threads.In some instance,Thead A may have worked 5 minutes,but Thead B didn't start.